# Linq filter model by another Table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, controller

I have two separate tables in my solution: Tickets and UsersInRoles.  Each Ticket has a Technician attached to it that looks at a third table: Users.  However, A users role is not saved in the Users Table; it is saved in the UsersInRoles table. Now I need to filter all tickets by technicians that have a role of New Media. I have searched and this are two different approaches that I have and neither is working.

First Approach:

```
var NewMediaIds = db.usersInRoles.Select(nm => nm.RoleId == new Guid(Properties.Settings.Default.NewMediaID)).ToList();
model = model.Where(t => NewMediaIds.Contains(t.TechnicianId));
```

and I get this error:

> Error 2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Guid' to
>   'bool'    C:\Dev\HelpDesk\HelpDesk.WebUI\Controllers\TicketController.cs  561 67  HelpDesk.WebUI
>
> Error 1   The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List.Contains(bool)' has some
>   invalid
>   arguments C:\Dev\HelpDesk\HelpDesk.WebUI\Controllers\TicketController.cs  561 46  HelpDesk.WebUI

Second Approach:

```
model = model.Where(t => t.TechnicianId == db.usersInRoles.Where(u => u.RoleId == new Guid(Properties.Settings.Default.NewMediaID)).UserId);
```

and I get this error:

> Error 3   'System.Linq.IQueryable' does not
>   contain a definition for 'UserId' and no extension method 'UserId'
>   accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   C:\Dev\HelpDesk\HelpDesk.WebUI\Controllers\TicketController.cs  563 153 HelpDesk.WebUI

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to get UserId from `IQueryable`. You need to get the `FirstOrDefault` of the list, then get UserId of that:

```
model = model.Where(t => t.TechnicianId == db.usersInRoles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.RoleId == new Guid(Properties.Settings.Default.NewMediaID)).UserId);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `.FirstOrDefault();`

```
model = model.Where(t => NewMediaIds.Contains(t.TechnicianId)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Fenrir, thank you for the assistance but I am still getting the same error with that.

Comment: On a second thought. I'm guessing `model` is a list or IQueryable. So using First will not work.

Comment: Nava's answer seems like what I intended to get to with my answer but I messed up understanding exactly what the variables where containing.  I think that one should work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have navigation properties set up, then:

```
var model=db.Tickets.Where(t=>t.Technician.Roles.Any(r=>r.Name=="New Media"));
```

Navigation property from Ticket to Technician via technicianId.
Navigation property from Technician to Roles via cross reference table UserRoles (technicianID,RoleId).